# PowerBI: I can't filter a table by two PERCENTILE.INC variables?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm expecting this to return the values that are within those two percentile variables, but it returns nothing, however when I replace those variables with the actual percentile values, it works exactly as I expect it to. Can you not filter with percentile variables?

```
VAR h_min = percentile.inc(table[column], 0.2)
VAR h_max = percentile.inc(table[column], 0.4)

VAR result = CALCULATE(SUM(table[column]), table[column] >= h_min && table[column] < h_max)

RETURN result
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got no issue getting the correct answer with this measure:

```
Measure = 
VAR h_min = 
    PERCENTILE.INC('Table'[Column], 0.2)
VAR h_max = 
    PERCENTILE.INC('Table'[Column], 0.4)
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Table'[Column]), 
        'Table'[Column] >= h_min && 'Table'[Column] < h_max
    )
```

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with my answer? Didn't it solve your problem?